# Spawning a rectangle at a point marked by a letter in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

```
import random
import time


BLACK = (0,0,0)

t = 145, 138
a = 75, 258
b = 275, 258
e = 165, 378
g = 95, 498
s = 295, 498
f = 395, 378
h = 535, 498
c = 495, 258
j = 745, 258
i = 795, 498
d = 695, 378

nodes = [t, a, b, e, g, s, f, h, c, j, i, d]

def spawn():
    global trap
    rspawn = random.randint(0,3)
    tspawn = random.randint(0,3)
    trap = random.choice(nodes)
    global treasure
    if tspawn == 0:
         treasure = 't'
    elif tspawn == 1:
        treasure = 'a'
    elif tspawn == 2:
        treasure = 'e'
    elif tspawn ==3:
        treasure = 'g'
    global rstart
    if rspawn == 0:
        rstart = 'c'
    elif rspawn == 1:
        rstart = 'j'
    elif rspawn == 2:
        rstart = 'd'
    elif rspawn ==3:
        rstart = 'i'
    if rspawn == 'c':
        trap != 'c'
    elif rspawn == 'j':
        trap != 'j'
    elif rspawn == 'i':
        trap != 'i'
    elif rspawn == 'd':
        trap != 'd'
spawn()
```

Right so this is what I have so far, what I'm trying to do is get a square to spawn at the same place as the trap and the trap spawns randomly, for the spawning of the trap I have trap = random.choice(nodes) and above you can see the nodes. I tried doing this using pygame.draw.rect because we are working in pygame but I don't know how to insert the coordinates so that whenever it spawns the random coordinates are there in the pygame.draw.rect.

Answer (score 0):

If the only problem is how to use PyGames `draw.rect()` function, than it is as easy as that:

pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (x, y, width, height), linewidth) draws a rectangle on the surface.

- `x` and `y` are the coordinates of the upper left hand corner
- `width` and `height` are the width and height of the rectangle
- `linewidth` is the thickness of the line and its optional

If you want to draw for instance a rectangle on the screen at the coordinates `(50, 50)` with a size of `10 x 10` pixels, call

```
 pygame.draw.rect(screen, (55, 155, 255), (50, 50, 10, 10))
```